# Does @DynamoDBAttribute support document paths in the attribute name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've checked the DynamoDB documentation, and I can't find anything to confirm or deny whether this is allowed.

Is it valid to use a [Document Path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedElements.DocumentPathExamples) for the `attributeName` of [`@DynamoDBAttribute`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAttribute.html), as in this code snippet?

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class MyClass {

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="object.nestedObject.myAttribute")
    private String myAttribute;
    .
    .
    .
    // Getters & Setters, etc
}
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I am specifically trying to find out whether document paths are valid in the `@DynamoDBAttribute` Java annotation as a way to directly access a nested value. I know that document paths work in general when specifying a query, but this question is specifically about DynamoDBMapper annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to reference a nested path using the attribute name in a `@DynamoDBAttribute`. I needed to use a POJO type with an added`@DynamoDBDocument` annotation to represent each level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the attribute name can have `Dot` on it. However, in my opinion, it is not recommended to have `Dot` on attribute name. Usually, the `Dot` will be used to navigate the tree in `Map` attribute.

> The following are the naming rules for DynamoDB:
>
> All names must be encoded using UTF-8, and are case-sensitive.
>
> Table names and index names must be between 3 and 255 characters long,
>   and can contain only the following characters:
>
> a-z
>
> A-Z
>
> 0-9
>
> _ (underscore)
>
> - (dash)
>
> . (dot)
>
> Attribute names must be between 1 and 255 characters long.

**Accessing Map Elements:-**

> The dereference operator for a map element is . (a dot). Use a dot as
>   a separator between elements in a map:
>
> MyMap.nestedField
>
> MyMap.nestedField.deeplyNestedField

I can create the item with attribute name containing `Dot` and query the item using FilterExpression successfully.

It works similarly in all language AWS SDKs. As long as data type is defined as String, it would work as expected.

**Some JS examples:-**

**Create Item:-**

```
var table = "Movies";
var year = 2017;
var title = "putitem data test 2";
var dotAttr = "object.nestedObject.myAttribute";        

var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Item:{
        "yearkey": year,
        "title": title,
        "object.nestedObject.myAttribute": "S123"
    },
    ReturnValues : 'NONE'
};
```

**Update:-**

It works fine with `@DynamoDBAttribute` annotation as well.

```
private String dotAttr;
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "object.nestedObject.myAttribute")
    public String getDotAttr() {
        return dotAttr;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, but do you know if this will work specifically with the higher-level DynamoDBMapper and the `@DynamoDBAttribute` annotation?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the myAttribute is present inside Map object? If this is the case, I think I misunderstood your question and my answer is not correct.

Comment: Yes. I guess with the way DynamoDBMapper works, both `object` and `nestedObject` would be Java objects that have been stored in DynamoDB as Maps.